# Function or Procedure to navigate through user forms

Tags: vba, office365, ms-word

I am using the Office365 version of Word. I have some VBA user forms that I'd like to create a function or procedure to navigate through. Currently, there are 40 form objects named Form01, Form02, Form03, etc. and the user must navigate through them sequentially. I have placed code in each to navigate forward and back.

```
Private Sub btnContinue_Click()
    Form02.Hide
    Form03.Show
End Sub

Private Sub btnBack_Click()
    Form02.Hide
    Form01.Show
End Sub
```

However, if I ever need to change my form names, it's going to be an effort to fix every button reference. I also attempted to embed a page reference in my code and then use a function to calculate the next or prior page, but I cannot figure out a way to turn that from a string value back to an object reference. What might I be missing?

Comment: An effort? Can you not just do a simple search/replace on the entire project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:
In a shared, common module:

```
Public Sub showNextForm(currentFormName As String)
    nextFormName = "Form" & Format((CInt(Right(currentFormName, 2)) + 1), "00")

    For Each uForm In VBA.UserForms 'Loop through all loaded userforms
        If uForm.Name = currentFormName Then uForm.Hide
        If uForm.Name = nextFormName Then
            uForm.Show
            nextFormLoaded = True
        End If
    Next uForm

    If Not nextFormLoaded Then
        Set nextForm = UserForms.Add(nextFormName) 'Load next userform if it's not already loaded
        nextForm.Show
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub showPreviousForm(currentFormName As String)
    prevFormName = "Form" & Format((CInt(Right(currentFormName, 2)) - 1), "00")

    For Each uForm In VBA.UserForms 'Loop through all loaded userforms, and hide current one
        If uForm.Name = currentFormName Then uForm.Hide
        If uForm.Name = prevFormName Then
            uForm.Show
            prevFormLoaded = True
        End If
    Next uForm

    If Not prevFormLoaded Then
        Set prevForm = UserForms.Add(prevFormName) 'Load previous userform if it's not already loaded
        prevForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, in each userform, you would have the 'Back' button call

```
showPreviousForm Me.Name
```

And the 'Next' button call

```
showNextForm Me.Name
```